# Java Sax tree (duplicate attributes)

Tags: java, xml, duplicates, sax

Im trying to make a program which will build a tree from xml document via SAX parser.
But in result names of tags build sucsessful , but in attributes I see only attribute of last tag.

What is wrong with [code](http://pastebin.com/jYXNYg31)?
Print to tree is in tag.toString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change line 48 into:

```
Tag t = new Tag(eName, new org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl(attrs));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are storing the `Attributes` instance for each `Tag`, and that the `Attributes`instance is reused for each each call to `startElement()` invokation. Thus, every `Tag` will will see the same attributes instance with the same content, that of the last one constructed by the parser. You will have to create a copy (or a Map or something else) of the actual attributes for each Tag.